# Instant app, Try Now button does not appear in play store

Tags: android, google-play, android-instant-apps, dynamic-feature-module

i started with following github projects but these example are not working properly. I added missing parts as stated in the docs.
https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples/tree/main/InstantApps/urlless
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-dynamic-features

Here is the docs i read.
https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle
https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/feature-module-migration
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/instant-delivery

i try to implement a simple hello world instant app. I tried many things but try now button never appears in play store.

my app contains 2 module:

- app
- instant-app

build.gradle of app module :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 61
        versionName "61"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dynamicFeatures = [':instantapp']
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0"
    ...
}
```

build.gradle of my instant-app module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
    }
}

dependencies {
    
    implementation "com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0"
   
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml of my app module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest >

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    ...

</manifest>
```

AndroidManifest.xml of my instant-app module

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.test.instantapp"
    android:targetSandboxVersion="2">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" dist:onDemand="false"
        dist:title="Instant app title">
        <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
    </dist:module>

    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="false">
        <activity android:name=".InstantMainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

  
</manifest>
```

I generate a signed bundle and upload it in internal test in each of my try but it did not work. i tried it in prod environment too. Not work!

I tried to put applicationId "com.test.myapp" in both app module and instant-app module. I tried to made android:targetSandboxVersion="2" and android:targetSandboxVersion="1". Not work
.
Version code of my app is greater than version code of my instant-app as shown below.

I removed clearTextTraffic and added. Not work!

Some said me to take my instant app enabled code to take into production and upload a new upgraded instant app version. I did it, it did not work either.

I tried many many combinations which i cannot remember now. But try now button never appears. What is the missing part i cannot find ?

There are 3 different sayings for maximum size of instant-app module:

- 4 mb
- 10 mb
- 15 mb
  Why the source codes and docs are conflicting too much and there is no working code in github ? If i didn't see working samples in play store, i would think instant apps are dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

open play store -> select app-> open advanced settings -> add release type instant app

[image]

Then upload your instant app from instant apps only option:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Perhaps you can mark this as the accepted answer? For me I get the following error message when I try to deploy as describe: "You should publish your app before you create an instant app release". Did you run into it? Tnx

Comment: I did it accepted answer. Could you please upvote my question and answer :) Probably you are trying to upload it from production. You can try to upload it using internal testing.

Comment: I needed to upload once to a "Closed Testing" Track, and afterwards the message was gone (also in Internal)

Comment: Note that "Release types" has been renamed to "Form factors"

Comment: @OdedBenDov Hi, may I ask what were your steps with resolving the issue? You just uploaded the "full" app to Closed Testing track once and after that you continued to use Internal testing track? I ran into the same issue and am furious with that.. Not even Google Play support is able to help me with it.